# set header with http.get request javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, http-headers

hello I want to set the header of this exact http example

```
    var http = require('http');
    var request = http.get($scope.getUrl(item), function (response) {
        //something here
     };
```

tried it like this :

```
response.headers = "Range: bytes=0 - 10";
```

it didn't work as I want

Comment: If your code is making a *request*, the response headers are set by the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setHeader method. like this:

```
  var http = require('http');
    var request = http.get($scope.getUrl(item), function (response) {
        response.setHeader("Range", "bytes=0 - 10");
     };
```

Comment: I get this error when I tried setHeader instead of header :
response.setHeader is not a function at ClientRequest.<anonymmous>